# Why we square while doing the proof of √2 is irrational?

Tags: real-numbers, radicals, alternative-proof, rationality-testing

When we prove that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational by the method of contradiction, 
we assume $\sqrt 2$ is a rational number:

$\sqrt 2 = a/b$

Squaring both sides,
$2  = a^2/b^2$.

Here is my question: is there another way to derive a contradiction without squaring?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: In general proving a number is irrational is not easy. We have to use the properties of the number to prove that it is irrational. One property of square roots is that $(\sqrt{x})^2 = x$ which leaves us with an integer on the left hand side and a rational number on the right hand side, i.e. of $2 = a^2/b^2$.

Comment: @Eff In fact, that is more or less the *only* property of square roots, hence this fact  more or less *must* be used

Comment: When we are proving that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational then we are actually not dealing at all with the real number $\sqrt{2}$ rather in reality we are proving that there is no rational number whose square is $2$. In general proving the irrationality of any algebraic number is essentially a theorem in the theory of rational numbers and is proved using elementary algebra.

Comment: Unfortunately show that its decimal expansion is not periodic is not be neither feasible by a human being nor by a computer.

Comment: "Here is the problem: if we will not square, what will happen?": this is a pretty enigmatic question. Of course, not squaring will no cause the end of the universe. If you don't square, nothing will happen at all. In particular, you not making a step in the direction of solving the problem.

Comment: You could also use the rational root theorem to find that if $x^2-2=0$ has a positive rational solution, it must be either $1$ or $2$. But you do need to square _those_ candidates in order to discover that neither of them is _actually_ a root.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Another way is to choose integers $p,q$ such that $q > 0$ and $\frac{p}{q} = \sqrt{2}$ and $q$ is minimum. Then $q<p<2q$ and $\frac{p}{q} = \sqrt{2} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{2q}{p}$ and so $\sqrt{2} = \frac{2q-p}{p-q}$, contradicting choice of $q$. But I can't post this as the question is closed.

Answer (score 4):

We square to be able to use the properties of integers instead of fractions and irrational numbers. Let us see how this plays into the proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational:

Proof by contradiction - Suppose $\sqrt{2}$ is rational and thus can be written as a fraction $\frac{a}{b}.$ We can square both sides to get $2 = \frac{a^2}{b^2}.$ Rearranging, we have that $a^2 = 2b^2.$ But we see that no perfect square could be double another perfect square because one of the integers $a$ or $b$ would have an odd power of $2.$ Thus, $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

As you can see, squaring allows us to use properties of integers to complete the task.

Comment: Thanks , your answer helps me in clearing my doubt !!!

Comment: Thank you !!!! It helps me !!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't square, all you can write is

$$\sqrt2=\frac pq,$$ which leads you nowhere. Squaring offers much better opportunities.